# Upload File to WCF using RestSharp

Tags: c#, wcf, restsharp

I have searched for this but did not find the answer.
I need to upload a file ( image or PDF) to a WCF REST service using RestSharp.
I have used AddFile() method, but the service is not hit ( I added a break-point on the very first line of the method), and the returned response is an empty string.

I tried both byte[] and Stream.
The web services is :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void NotesAttachment(Stream input);
```

Please I need example for both the service and how to call it from the client.

Using C# 4.5.1 on VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my example
**IServcie1.cs**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Task UploadStream(Stream stream);
```

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
public async Task UploadStream(Stream stream)
        {
            using (stream)
            {
                using (var file = File.Create(Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Uploads"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png")))
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(file);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Web.config**

```
      <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpbinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147473647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="mybinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147473647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <!--http and https are all supported.-->
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" bindingConfiguration="httpbinding" />
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client call example. Take the Postman as an example.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hello , thanks for your reply , I am receiving "Entity is too large" error. I added maxAllowedContentLength ,maxBufferPoolSize,maxStringContentLength,maxArrayLength,maxBytesPerRead but still have the error

Comment: This is because the default MaxReceivedMessageSize Property is 65536 bytes, about 64kb. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize?view=netframework-4.0  you could increase the property value lest encountering the error. Refer to my above-modified code.